# Sublist pattern matching

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, pattern-matching

Is there any way to simplify the following pattern:

```
{p___, {a___, x_, x_, b___}, q___} :> {p, {a, x, b}, q}
```

Ie. where I remove duplicated elements within sublists?

Edit: Just to be clear, I have the feeling p and q could be removed here, but well I'm not certain :)

Thanks

Comment: Think. If you remove the p and q and you happened to have two adjacent sublists that were identical, what would happen then? Something like {{3,4},{5,7,7,2},{5,7,7,2},{2,8}}  Compare that example with and without the p and q and see what happens. Then think about it until you can explain what happened. Then try all this using /. and //. It all depends on what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Well exactly, that's why I kept them. But since p and q remain at the same place I thought I could have removed them. Besides, it assumes here that I'm working at the second level of my main list, but what if I didn't know which level they were at? Anyway, it might just be the most simple expression but I had the intuition it wasn't so. And btw it's a repeated pattern //. here.

Comment: You could look at `DeleteDuplicates` or `Split` + `First`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several demonstrative examples:

```
list = {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 3, 5}};

list /. {p___, {a___, x_, x_, b___}, q___} :> {p, {a, x, b}, q}
(* {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 3, 5}} *)

list /. {a___, x_, x_, b___} :> {a, x, b}
(* {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 3, 5}} *)

Replace[list, {a___, x_, x_, b___} :> {a, x, b}, {1}]
(* {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 5}} *)
```

I think the last one is what you are looking for.

If you want to delete many sequential duplicates with patterns you can use

```
Replace[list, {a___, Repeated[x_, {2, ∞}], b___} :> {a, x, b}, {1}]
```

Comment: Sweet. Yeah the last answer with the levelspec argument is what I was looking for. It's too bad it can't be expressed using the /. syntax though. One last question, I'm not certain why the first pattern (the which I submitted doesn't catch the {1, 3, 3, 5} list.

Comment: @Neuschwanstein It is because the whole list matches the pattern and `/.` applies the substitution, but this substitution eliminate only one duplicate. You should use `//.` (`ReplaceRepeated`) to apply replacement repeatedly. Note, that `ReplaceRepeated` is very slow for big lists due to matching the whole list a lot of times.

Answer (score 3):

Map `ReplaceAll` at `Level` 1:

```
# /. {a___, x_, x_, b___} :> {a, x, b} & /@ list
(* {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 5}} *)
```

`Map` `DeleteDuplicates` at `Level` 1:

```
DeleteDuplicates /@ list
(* {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 5}} *)
```

Alternative methods to `ReplaceRepeated` to get `{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 5}}`:

```
FixedPoint[# /. {a___, x_, x_, b___} :> {a, x, b} &, list]
(* {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 5}} *)

Map[DeleteDuplicates, list, {0, 1}]
(* {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 5}} *)
```

And to get `{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 3, 5}}`:

```
Map[# /. {a___, x_, x_, b___} :> {a, x, b} &, list, {0}]
(* {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 3, 5}} *)
```

or

```
Map[DeleteDuplicates, list, {0}]
(* {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 3, 5}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I don't missunderstand your question this could be a good candidat for `ReplaceRepeated`

```
list = {1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 7};

list //. {head___, x_, x_, tail___} :> {head, x, tail}
```

> {1, 2, 3, 1, 7}

To scrutinise @ ybeltukov's excellent answer and your nice but ambiguous question

```
matrix = {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 3, 5}};

matrix //. {head___, x_, x_, tail___} :> {head, x, tail}
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 5}}

Answer (score 1):

Another option to consider is to only (repeatedly) replace if the repeated item is an atom:

```
rule = {a___, x_?AtomQ, x_, b___} :> {a, x, b}
```

In action:

```
{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 3, 5}} //. rule
```

> `{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 5}}`

Answer (score 1):

- Duplicated elements in a list can be removed by `DeleteDuplicates` without changing list order. Duplicated elements can be non-consecutive.
- Using `Union` will sort the list which may or may not be desired.
- `Sequence*` functions were introduced in 2018 and are a natural fit for the task or removing consecutively appearing elements.

---

```
Entity["WolframLanguageSymbol"
, "SequenceReplace"]["DateIntroduced"]
```

[image]

```
Clear["Global`*"]
list = {
   {1, 2, 3}
   , {1, 2, 3}
   , {1, 2, 2, 3}
   , {1, 3, 3, 5}
   , {1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, {5}, {5}, 6, 7, 8}
   , {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 4, 5, 5, 9}
   };
```

where a few additional test cases have been introduced to demonstrate removal of repeated/sublisted items.

The following deletes any number of similar and consecutive elements in `list` but not inside the sublists.

```
SequenceReplace[list, {x_ ..} ->  x]
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 3, 5}, {1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, {5}, {5},
> 6, 7, 8}, {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 4, 5, 5, 9}}

Defining this as a function and applying it to each sublist:

```
f = SequenceReplace[#, {x_ ..} ->  x] &
f /@ list
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 5}, {1, 3, 4, 5, {5}, 6, 7,
> 8}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 4, 5, 9}}

More selectivity with repetition count can be achieved using options for `Repeated`.

Try: `f@(f /@ list)`

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use `Cases`, `Tally` and `Union` as follows:

```
list = {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 2}, {3, 1, 3, 5, 3}};

delRepeated[l_List, opts___] := Which[opts === Null, 
                                      Cases[l, x_ :> Tally[x][[All, 1]]], 
                                             opts === "Sorted", Union /@ l];

 delRepeated[list]

(*{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {3, 1, 5}}*)

 delRepeated[list, "Sorted"]

(*{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 5}}*)
```

Comment: What is `list2`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error, @Syed, it's that I tried it with another list that I denoted like this and when copying I forgot to change it. :-)